# What are some good tools for data analysis / database visualisation / reporting

Tags: mysql, reporting, relational-database, analysis

I have developed a web application driven by a mysql database that stores information about users, site usage, photo uploads (its a photo based site) etc. I have multiple databases storing data for different aspects of the site. I want to be able to produce reports for some of the questions I will have about how the site is growing and how it is being used. For example, how many new users have uploaded over a certain number of photos this month.

What tools are available to analyse databases - i have been using a trial version of microsoft access and exporting each of the database as an xml file and importing to access, where I created the relationships and used the query wizard to generate some queries and reports. These are the activities I want to do and they produced the reports I want to have. I also want to be able to run queries across databases...

What other tools to people use for this sort of task with mysql databases? Is there any good advice / training materials about the workflow for creating such reports and managing this activity over time - eg should I take weekly exports of databases and run the queries to generate the reports?

What are people's experiences of this type of task?

all advice, input welcome.

Comment: Do you search a freeware or can it cost money?

Comment: Dont mind spending money on a good tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to business intelligence, the art of making information out of data.

A usual architecture is Source --> ETL --> Data warehouse --> Reporting tools

ETL : extract transform load (today you are copying your databases but some free tools can help you change that : CloverETL, Talend, etc...)

Data warehouse : this is the place where you put your data and prepare it to be easily used in reports

Reporting tools: many free tools exist today such as BIRT, JasperReports, etc... but I strongly recommend QlikView, the personal version is free (if you don't need to share your results), it's a very easy tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking as someone who used to earn a living developing on MSAccess, I would strongly recommend using just about anything else.

Crystal reports is a good option. But IIRC the free version has disappeared.

You might also have a look at [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports), [ReportMan](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/), [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/), [DataVision](http://datavision.sourceforge.net/) and [Agata](http://www.agata.org.br/)

Answer (score 0):

If you does not want download the data every time it seems a good idea to install a software on the server. If you want a reporting software on the server then which platform do you use on server?

If you can't install software on server then you can use a PHP-MySQL Bridge. A PHP script. With a JDBC driver you can access it. Then you can use a Java based reporting tool. For example the free (yet fully functional) [designer](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer) from **[i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/de/products/crystal-clear)** (used to be i-net Crystal-Clear).

Comment: Our server is Linux, apache2, PHP5, MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) a reporting solution based on PHP and mySQL. myDBR is very easy to install and lets you create reports within a few minutes.

You write your reports in SQL and myDBR then takes care of the layout and display of the report. This is different from most other solutions in that it allows you to concentrate on the content of your report instead of having to spend too much time on the look and feel.

Here is a short example on how you could create a usage statistic for your site:

```
select 'dbr.chart', 'Column', 'Usage statistics';
select name, count(*) 
from user_access
group by name;
```

More examples are available at the [myDBR demo](http://mydbr.com/demo) site.
myDBR is available as a free community version and a paid premium version (129 EUR).